# How to make a waterfall graph in power bi with start and end as different measures of the same table?

Tags: graph, powerbi, measure, waterfall

I want to create a waterfall graph for the following dataset:

[image]

In the "fields" list, we can see different measures of the same table. I want to start the waterfall graph with avg_bdtech_approval and end with avg_final_approval with avg_costing and avg_credit in between. What do I enter as the category, breakdown and values for this?

PS: All these measures are no. of days between different processes and a waterfall graph will depict them perfectly.

I want to make a waterfall graph like this, with the fields I mentioned:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get good waterfall use only one measure in values (Numerical) and only one dimension column (string or Date) in Category and only one dimension column (string or Date) in breakdown.